# What causes most files to open in Wireshark from Firefox?

Tags: nautilus, firefox

Recently I've noticed most files open in Wireshark, which naturally says there's an error. For example, I download a pdf, click it from the download button dropdown, and it opens immediatly in Wireshark!??

When I double-click the file in Nautilus it opens normally, and right clicking, going to properties panel, I see it has the proper program set to open the file.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file:

```
~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list
```

Delete the line starting with:

```
application/octet-stream
```

(that points to wireshark).

Save and quit.